# Where should I store in app purchase 'Consumable' information

Tags: iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app where users purchase tokens in order to interact with the app.

So if the user purchases 100 tokens his 'token' count would equal 100, then if the user purchases another 100 tokens, it would equal 200 tokens, and so on and so forth.

Question is where should I store the 'token' count for the app!? I want the user to have access to his 'tokens' no matter what device he uses (iPhone, Android, website...) All the user needs to do is login to his account on the device.

Comment: As far as I know, consumables can not be restored (therefore, not shared among devices). You must implement your own, server-based sync logic to preserve the user's coins across sessions on different devices (and prevent them form e.g. using the same coin twice).

Answer (score 0):

you need to store it in an database where you can access from iphone, android and website. it can be an self hosted database where you need to write your server side api or it can be a cloud service like FireBase.

my advice: add also an transaction log for each time the user uses the token or recharge the token. in case of trouble you can see where the tokens are gone or how he reloaded the tokens and you can show this log also to the user

Comment: if utilizing firebase, can you suggest the firebase rules to secure the token count so that the users can 'inflate' the actual tokens purchased?

Comment: yes - you should secure your data. how you restrict the access depends on your database.